Is there any way to convert call voice audio/sound (Duo/Meet call) to default audio on rooted devices?
My purpose is to route/convert the call voice audio from a Android phone to TV speaker via chromecast in screen mirror mode.
Becasue chromecast can only output the media sound/audio from default audio source (like music or youtube...) to TV speaker in screen mirror mode but for call voice audio/sound, it outputs via phone speaker. Therefore, I am looking the way (by apps, Magisk module, editing system file...) to route/convert call voice audio (voice_downlink) to default audio which can be outputted from TV speaker via chromecast.
P/S: I have been trying create an app which records call voice audio (MediaRecoder API) and streaming data to chromecast via nanohttp server but the latency is huge for a call (5 to 10 seconds).
Please let me know if you have any idea. Thanks
